# How to make GIFs open with navigator by default?

Tags: animation, gif, presentation

I have several looped animated GIFs, that I like to place in one USB stick. I'd like the person who plugs this stick in whatever computer to be able to read the GIFs by clicking on them. By default, these GIFs wont be opened with some navigator or web browser. Instead these will be opened with something like "preview" or "picture viewer", which will display all the frames one by one.

How to make those animated GIFs immediately readable, in some user friendly way?
(without adding some readme.txt file telling : open gifs in chrome)

Answer (score 2):

Upload the GIFs onto an image sharing site, like imgur. Then all you need to do is send the person the link.

The above method also avoids the use of memory sticks altogether, as these are sometimes seen as a security threat in some organisations.

Animated GIFs are designed to be viewed in a Browser. Windows default photo viewer will not play them.  You could tell the person to click and drag the GIF files into their browser.  There is no way to get a gif file to open in a browser by default on someone else's computer, since you'd have to change settings on that person's computer.

Answer (score 2):

Create an HTML file with the GIF(s) that you want to share placed in the HTML file as images. Then the person receiving the files can click on the HTML file (which will open in their browser by default) and view the animated GIFs as intended.

To make things more friendly and idiot proof, I would place the GIFs in a folder on the drive, link them to the HTML file from within that folder and call the HTML file something like “double_click_me.html”.